# Pokemon Go Trainer club account got reset after update

Tags: pokemon-go

So I have 2 accounts, one Gmail which is level 7 and is intact after update. other one is a Trainer Club account which is level 22 and it got completely reset after update to a level new account, had to choose Pokemon and nickname all over again.
I have tried everything I could find on internet in past 2 days but nothing worked so far.
I spent so much time and money on this account that I won't be able to start all over again.

Comment: What OS are you on?

Comment: @Dragonrage  iOS 9.3.3

Comment: are you logged into a gmail account on Safari?

Comment: i logged out of my gmail, even removed my gmail account from my mail app, also cleared all cookie and history on safari. the thing is its not about my gmail account, its about my trainers club account which i created using a Yahoo account.

Comment: sorry then, I got nothing. Hopefully someone else can help. Possibly try opening a support ticket with Niantic.

Comment: thanks for your time and help :)  i already opened a few tickets but no luck so far.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest opening a ticket with pokemon trainer club, not niantic. Apparently the PTC login goes to a different Nintendo/Pokemon Company server before going to niantic, as thousands of PTC-login players were locked out during server maintenance on launch week, while Google-login players were far better off, and many managed to play just fine.

TL;DR, see if Nintendo can help you out. Since these accounts can have money poured into them, there's probably a legal failsafe to prevent a server hiccup or an accidental deletion from completely destroying all account data.